# Fatal Exception in Game Development with Cocos2D

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone, import

I'm new in Java and I getting a Fatal Exception with Cocos2D.
My Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // landscape orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // view
    CCGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(glSurfaceView);

    // sensor manager
    configSensormanager();

    // configure CCDirector 
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setScreenSize(320, 480);

    // Starts title screen
    CCScene scene = new TitleScreen().scene();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);


}

private void configSensormanager() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    DeviceSettings.setSensorManager(sensorManager);
}
```

ERROR

```
05-15 17:42:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 17:42:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): Process: br.com.spaceandtime, PID: 3001
05-15 17:42:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/cocos2d/nodes/CCDirector;
05-15 17:42:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): at br.com.spaceandtime.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
```

I already tried change the cocos2d lib but it's not works
and I'm from Brazil so... sorry for my bad english